# Elastic Modulus in Arbitrary Direction for Orthotropic Material

Tags: mechanical-engineering, elastic-modulus

Suppose I have a material with an elastic modulus of E<sub>x</sub> in the x direction and an Elastic modulus of E<sub>y</sub> in the y direction.

How would I find the effective elastic modulus in an arbitrary direction (say for an angle theta from the x axis)?

Answer (score 1):

The elastic modulus can be shown to be:
$\frac{E_x*E_y}{\sqrt{E_x^2sin^2(\theta)+E_y^2cos^2(\theta)}}$

Here is the derivation:

$\epsilon_x=\frac{\sigma cos(\theta)}{E_x}$

$\epsilon_y=\frac{\sigma sin(\theta)}{E_x}$

$\epsilon=\sqrt{\epsilon_x^2+\epsilon_y^2}=\sigma\sqrt{\frac{cos(\theta)}{E_x^2}+\frac{sin(\theta)}{E_y^2}}$

$E=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}=\frac{E_x*E_y}{\sqrt{E_x^2sin^2(\theta)+E_y^2cos^2(\theta)}}$